# Looping and appending hashes to an array

Tags: ruby

I want to create an array of hashes like this:

```
[
  {"start"=>1, "end"=>2},
  {"start"=>2, "end"=>3},
  {"start"=>3, "end"=>4},
  {"start"=>4, "end"=>5},
  {"start"=>5, "end"=>6}
]
```

When I try this code:

```
foo = 1
bar = 2
hash = {}
array = []
5.times do
  hash['start'] = foo
  hash['end'] = bar
  array << hash
  foo += 1
  bar += 1
end
```

the `hash` values change inside `array` while looping and hashes are added to it. `array` becomes:

```
[
  {"start"=>5, "end"=>6},
  {"start"=>5, "end"=>6},
  {"start"=>5, "end"=>6},
  {"start"=>5, "end"=>6},
  {"start"=>5, "end"=>6}
]
```

Why does this happen when:

```
foo = 1
array = []
5.times do
  array << foo
  foo += 1
end
array # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

does not change the numeral inside `array` during the loop?

Comment: use `array << hash.dup` instead of `array << hash` because of you've added here just references to hash, not the hashs themselves.

Comment: I'd use `(1..6).each_cons(2).map { |a, b| { start: a, end: b } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because a hash is mutable. if you have `foo = {"start" => 1}`, and do `foo["start"] += 1`, then, `foo` still points to the same hash although it is modified to `{"start" => 2}`. It does not change the reference. If you have multiple copies of this same object in an array and change modify one of them, then all of them will be modified.

On the other hand, a numeral is not mutable; if you had `foo = 1`, and do `foo += 1`, then `foo` will now point to `2`, which is a different object from `1`.

Comment: Great answer. Really short and explains the mechanism behind the result.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new hash each time.

```
foo = 1
array = []

5.times do
  array << { 'start' => foo, 'end' => foo + 1 }
  foo += 1
end
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
array << hash.dup
```

instead of:

```
array << hash
```

because of you've added here just references to hash, not the hashs themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code to create a new hash in every loop iteration:

```
foo = 1
bar = 2
array = []
5.times do
  hash = {}
  hash['start'] = foo
  hash['end'] = bar
  array << hash
  foo += 1
  bar += 1
end
puts array
```

Otherwise you are always changing the same object, that's the reason you end with the same hash as array elements.

As a quick literature on subject taken from [here](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/ruby/doc_bundle/Newcomers/ruby.html#objects):

> Ruby variables hold references to objects and the = operator copies
>   the references. Also, a self assignment such as a += b is actually
>   translated to a = a + b. Therefore it may be advisable to be aware
>   whether in a certain operation you are actually creating a new object
>   or modifying an existing one.
>
> For example, string << "another" is faster than string += "another"
>   (no extra object creation), so you would be better off using any
>   class-defined update-method (if that is really your intention), if it
>   exists. However, notice also the "side effects" on all other variables
>   that refer to the same object:

```
        a = 'aString'
        c = a
        a += ' modified using +='
        puts c    # -> "aString"

        a = 'aString'
        c = a
        a << ' modified using <<'
        puts c    # -> "aString modified using <<"
```